# Trying to re-style some jQuery elements with css

Tags: jquery, css

I have this test page: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=305

You see the black bar with 3 tabs about half way down on the page? I am trying to restyle the color of it.

If you look at the page with FireBug, these elements are involved:

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
```

So I tried to add this css to my own css files to over-write the defaults:

```
.ui-tabs-nav .ui-helper-reset .ui-widget-header .ui-helper-clearfix .ui-corner-all
{
    background-color: gray;
}
```

but no changes happened.  I am not sure if this is the way to do it or not. How can I restyle the background strip color of the black bar with the tabs? And how can I change the color of the text on it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule isn't going to work because `ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all` are all the different classes assigned to that element, if you want to change the style of that element you just need to restyle one of those classes.

The one with the background in particular is `ui-widget-header` so you'd have to do:

```
.ui-widget-header
{
    background-image: none;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

By having a css rule for `.ui-tabs-nav .ui-helper-reset .ui-widget-header .ui-helper-clearfix .ui-corner-all` its going to be trying to find an element with the class `.ui-tabs-nav` followed by a parent element inside that one with the class `.ui-helper-reset` followed by a parent inside that element with the class `.ui-widget-header` and so forth...

Comment: U just added that to the css here: http://www.problemio.com/main.css but it isn't showing up on the page I linked to in my question.  Any idea why?

Comment: If you look at the element in Firebug or another inspector you'll see background is actually styling it the problem is the class `ui-widget-header` also has the striped image displaying so you can't see your background color, I updated my answer to remove the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in Chrome dev tools, though you may actually want to take out the spaces like this: .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-nav

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-tabs-nav.ui-helper-reset.ui-widget-header.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all
{
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: This is right - the issue is that you shouldn't have the spaces between the classes. When you have multiple classes with spaces in between, to CSS, that means decendent elements, not the same element with multiple classes.

That being said, you should only need one class, maybe two, tops. Not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use ui-widget-header class

```
.ui-widget-header {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the rules you can see that the background is applied from the `.ui-widget-header` rule.

```
.ui-widget-header
 {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_8_333333_40x40.png") repeat scroll 50% 50% #333333;
    border: 1px solid #A3A3A3;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You need to override this with

```
.ui-widget-header{
    background-image: none;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following rules, make sure that you add them after the jquery-ui css, so as to override them, else write them on the above css itself.

Normal State :

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header.ui-state-default{background:grey;color:red;}
```

Hover State :

```
ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header.ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content.ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header.ui-state-focus { 
background:grey;color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I  just looked in firebug and changed the property of

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a
```

and it worked. Also, when you are editing colors, try to use # instead of names.